# cascading additional switches good or run wire directly from main switch

Tags: networking

We have a network design as shown below. Now my concern is if the additional switches are affecting our network throughput or latency or causing any network collisions. If I run directly 21 lines from the first 36 ports switch? Will I have any advantage by doing that?

```
 Router
 |
 Switch (36 ports unmanaged)
 |             |        |        |
 (4 different offices - each office 4 to 7 computers)

 Switch1 | switch2 | switch3 | switch4 (all unmanaged)
   |         |
  6 pc   |  4 pc    | 7 pc    | 4
```

Comment: This issue is discussed in great detail here: http://serverfault.com/questions/163962/what-is-the-disadvantage-to-cascading-multiple-switches

Comment: Hi, I read that before I posted my question. That helped me in understanding a bit about it. But  I felt like my scenario is little different and I expected answer specific to my situation.